# Are pointer values stable in Cocoa View callbacks?

Tags: cocoa

I'm implementing an `NSOutlineViewDataSource` (but it may as well be a `NSTableViewDataSource` or anything else). The `outlineView: objectValueForTableColumn: byItem:` method is being called quite a lot (obviously once per row) and I want to know which column is being requested. I can do this:

```
if ([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"myCol"])
```

but it feels terribly expensive, once per row per column.

Can I store a pointer to each `NSTableColumn *` and compare the pointer values? Comparing those woud be a lot quicker. Or are the pointers likely to change in the duration of the App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stability of an `NSTableColumn *` is just the same as the stability of an `NSTextField *`.

Most likely, the lifecycle of the object which is serving as the `NSOutlineViewDataSource` for your `NSOutlineView` will be very similar to the lifecycle of the `NSTableColumn`.

A typical pattern is to have an `NSWindowController` subclass instance serve as an outline view's data source, where the outline view is within a xib which has the window controller as the file's owner.  The table columns will be created soon after the window controller is initialized (and after the point that `-loadWindow` is called on the `NSWindowController`--to intercept this, override `-loadWindow` in the `NSWindowController` subclass to first call `[super loadWindow]` and then make use of the no-longer-`nil` pointers set up in Interface Builder) and will be destroyed soon after the window controller is deallocated.  From the time that `-loadWindow` is called until the time that `-dealloc` is called on the window controller, the same `NSTableColumns` will be in use (provided, of course that nothing in your own code mucks with them).

The only potential danger is that the outline view will call its data source after the data source has been deallocated.  To avoid this difficulty, set the outline view's data source to nil when the window controller is deallocated.